# success callback after knockout.js finishes rendering all the elements

Tags: jquery, foreach, knockout.js

I have implemented a knockout foreach binding, with multiple templates in the same page, one of the example is given here, what I am interested is in finding out when a block finishes rendering, I have tried `afterRender` and `afterAdd`, but I guess it runs for each element, and not after the whole loop is finished.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: Contacts, afterAdd: myPostProcessingLogic}">
  <li>
    <div class="list_container gray_bg mrgT3px">
      <div class="list_contact_icon"></div>
      <div class="contact_name"><span data-bind="text: first_name"></span> <span data-bind="text: last_name"></span></div>
      <div class="contact_number"><span data-bind="text: value"></span></div>
      <div class="callsms_container">
        <a href="#notification-box" class="notifcation-window">
          <div class="hover_btn tooltip_call">
            <div class="hover_call_icon"></div>
            <span>Call</span></div>
        </a>
        <a class="sendsms" href="#sendsms" rel="#sendsms">
          <div class="hover_btn tooltip_sms">
            <div class="hover_sms_icon"></div>
            <span>SMS</span></div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="hover_more_btn"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- close callsms container -->
      <div id="notification-box" class="notification-popup">
        <a href="#" class="close"><img class="btn_close" src="images/box_cross.png" /></a> <img class="centeralign" src="images/notification_call.png" /> <span>Calling... +44 7401 287366</span> </div>
      <!-- close notification box -->
      <!-- close list gray bg -->
      <div class="tooltip_description" style="display:none" id="disp"> asdsadaasdsad </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am interested in finding out just the success callback, when a loop finishes rendering.

here is my `afterAdd` function, which basically attaches some jQuery events, and nothing much.

```
myPostProcessingLogic = function(elements) { 
  $(function(){
      $(".list_container_callog").hover(function(){  
          $(".callsms_container", this).stop().animate({left:"0px"},{queue:false,duration:800});
      }, function() {
          $(".callsms_container", this).stop().animate({left:"-98%"},{queue:false,duration:800});
      });
  });
}
```

thanks in advance, and tell me there is a success callback :)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You have the `afterRender` callback in `knockout.js`:

```
foreach: { data: myItems, afterRender: renderedHandler }
```

[Here's documentation.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

Inside your handler check whether the length of the rendered collection is equal to the length of the items collection. If not don't execute the full rendered logic that you intend to use.

```
renderedHandler: function (elements, data) {
    if ($('#containerId').children().length === this.myItems().length) {
        // Only now execute handler
    }
}
```

Comment: i have already used that. the problem is that it called back after each element renders, while i am interested in finding out when all elements finish rendering

Comment: yes its the same i have a array of 10 items and its rendering 10 times.the problem i am getting is after every single render it execute the js with each element i just want it to execute after all the elements are displayed.

Comment: @user1487459 I have written some more example code. Adjust it according to what you have.

Comment: @user1487459 You are getting a reference to the rendered elements. You can retrieve the parent container from there and not use a single ID.

Comment: With an additional inner foreach knockout seems to bind the outer loop first which sabotages this approach... is there another way to process the foreach and everything inside of it and execute a function after that?

Comment: Careful: this handler will not be called when elements are removed from 'myItems" (model).

Answer (score 12):

Try wrapping the `ul` with

```
<div data-bind='template: {afterRender: myPostProcessingLogic }'>
```

It will only work the first time everything within the template is rendered. But you will only get the one call to myPostProcessingLogic. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8k8V5/2237/)

```
<div data-bind='template: {afterRender: myPostProcessingLogic }'>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: Contacts">
    <li>
      <div class="list_container gray_bg mrgT3px">
        <div class="list_contact_icon"></div>
        <div class="contact_name"><span data-bind="text: first_name"></span> <span data-bind="text: last_name"></span></div>
        <div class="contact_number"><span data-bind="text: value"></span></div>
        <div class="callsms_container">
          <a href="#notification-box" class="notifcation-window">
            <div class="hover_btn tooltip_call">
              <div class="hover_call_icon"></div>
              <span>Call</span></div>
          </a>
          <a class="sendsms" href="#sendsms" rel="#sendsms">
            <div class="hover_btn tooltip_sms">
              <div class="hover_sms_icon"></div>
              <span>SMS</span></div>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <div class="hover_more_btn"></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- close callsms container -->
        <div id="notification-box" class="notification-popup">
          <a href="#" class="close"><img class="btn_close" src="images/box_cross.png" /></a> <img class="centeralign" src="images/notification_call.png" /> <span>Calling... +44 7401 287366</span> </div>
        <!-- close notification box -->
        <!-- close list gray bg -->
        <div class="tooltip_description" style="display:none" id="disp"> asdsadaasdsad </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The function gets called before the contents are fully rendered.

Comment: This approach worked for me in combination with the Slick carousel library.

Answer (score 5):

Chuck Schneider's answer above is the best. 
I had to use containerless control as the foreach is on a tbody element:

```
<!-- ko template: {afterRender: SetupCheckboxes } -->
<tbody data-bind="foreach: selectedItems" id="gridBody">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap the foreach into another foreach loop using Knockout's container less method like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach:{data: Contacts, afterRender: myPostProcessingLogic }-->
<ul data-bind="foreach: $data}">
  <li>
    <div class="list_container gray_bg mrgT3px">
      <div class="list_contact_icon"></div>
      <div class="contact_name"><span data-bind="text: first_name"></span> <span data-bind="text: last_name"></span></div>
      <div class="contact_number"><span data-bind="text: value"></span></div>
      <div class="callsms_container">
        <a href="#notification-box" class="notifcation-window">
          <div class="hover_btn tooltip_call">
            <div class="hover_call_icon"></div>
            <span>Call</span></div>
        </a>
        <a class="sendsms" href="#sendsms" rel="#sendsms">
          <div class="hover_btn tooltip_sms">
            <div class="hover_sms_icon"></div>
            <span>SMS</span></div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="hover_more_btn"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- close callsms container -->
      <div id="notification-box" class="notification-popup">
        <a href="#" class="close"><img class="btn_close" src="images/box_cross.png" /></a> <img class="centeralign" src="images/notification_call.png" /> <span>Calling... +44 7401 287366</span> </div>
      <!-- close notification box -->
      <!-- close list gray bg -->
      <div class="tooltip_description" style="display:none" id="disp"> asdsadaasdsad </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 2):

In version 3.5 Knockout provides events to notify when the contents of a node have been bound

HTML

```
<div data-bind="childrenComplete: bindingComplete">...</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function bindingComplete(){
...
}
```

If you an create event binding expression at a point in the DOM that encapsulates all your child data binding expression, then it's tantamount to a page binding complete event

reference
https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-lifecycle-events.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution above works great. Additionally, if you need to use the foreach "as" option you can do it as so:

```
data-bind="foreach: { data: myItems, afterRender: renderedHandlet, as: 'myItem'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just recently made a pull request with knockout for them to add two events to define in the binding, unwrap, then call in the correct spots before rendering the items and after all items have rendered. I haven't heard anything back from them but this does exactly what you want to do but you don't have to write hacky code to get it to work. I'm surprised that nobody has made this request before. I used these callbacks that I added to the source to destroy and reinitialize a knockout bound jquery datatable. This was the simplest solution. I have seen many attempts online that try and do it differently but this is the simplest solution.

Pull request: --> [pr 1856](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1856)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.DataTablesForEach = {

  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function(node) {
      if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
      }
    });
    return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
      key = "DataTablesForEach_Initialized";

    var newValue = function() {
      return {
        data: value.data || value,
        beforeRenderAll: function(el, index, data) {

          if (ko.utils.domData.get(element, key)) {

            $(element).closest('table').DataTable().destroy();
          }
        },
        afterRenderAll: function(el, index, data) {
          $(element).closest('table').DataTable(value.options);
        }
      };
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, newValue, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);

    //if we have not previously marked this as initialized and there is currently items in the array, then cache on the element that it has been initialized
    if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (value.data || value.length)) {
      ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
    }

    return {
      controlsDescendantBindings: true
    };
  }
};
```

[Knockout Datatables JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zachpainter77/z8us2aej/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `afterRenderAll` callback in knockout.js:

> foreach: { data: myItems, afterRenderAll: myPostProcessingLogic }