# knockoutjs: afterrender causing massive slowdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got some code firing on afterrender on a knockoutjs foreach. The object it's running on is huge (>1000 elements) and I only want to know when the render is complete.

Right now I'm using the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254317/success-callback-after-knockout-js-finishes-rendering-all-the-elements?rq=1)

but it's VERY expensive and hangs the page until it completes.

the afterRender handler is:

```
ivm.renderHandler = function(elements, data) {
    if (elements[1].parentNode.children.length === ko.toJS(ivm.classList).length) {
        console.log("loaded");
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            revert: true
        });
        $(elements[1].parentNode).children().draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#sortable",
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid"
        });
```

I'm pretty sure it's the if() statement that's the problem, but I can't find any way to speed this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ivm.classList` is an observable array, calling `ko.toJS` is quite expensive since it does a deep copy and unwrapping of your view model. If all you need is the length of the observable array, it's easily accessible:

```
if (elements[1].parentNode.children.length === ivm.classList().length) {
```

Comment: Winner! I knew I was missing something obvious. Thanks!