# How to raise an event after knockout rendering is complete?

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

This jquery mobile table is being rendered with knockout.

```
<table data-role="table" id="report-table" class="ui-body-a ui-shadow ui-responsive table-stripe"
    data-column-btn-theme="a" data-column-btn-text="Spalten..." data-column-popup-theme="a" data-mode="columntoggle"">
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
            <th data-bind="text: $data.Caption, attr: { 'data-priority': 1 + Math.floor($index() / 4) }"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: rows, afterRender: tableRowAfterRender }">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns">
            <!-- ko template: { name: $data.template } -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To get the "columntoggle" to actually work, I currently use the "aferRender" event:

```
self.tableRowAfterRender = function (element, data) {
    // Skip unless data.Items()[i] is not the last element in the rows collections
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Items().length - 1; i++) {
        if (data.Items()[i] !== self.rows()[self.rows().length - 1].Items()[i])
            return;
    }

    // refresh table after 100ms delay
    setTimeout(function () { $("#report-table").table("refresh"); }, 100);
}
```

This is shaky, I hate the setTimeout() way of doing things, and this situation became quiet common for me with jquery mobile and knockout. I need a robust way to raise an event once all the knockout rendering or ideally once all the rendering concerned with elements inside the table-element is done. I was able to use custom bindings in some such situations, but I would not know how to do this here.

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254317/success-callback-after-knockout-js-finishes-rendering-all-the-elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254317/success-callback-after-knockout-js-finishes-rendering-all-the-elements)

Comment: @akhlesh: I saw that posting (even commented there), it is about (or at least seems satisfied with) getting an event when one foreach has rendered. I use the proposed technique in my example. But this does not help with nested foreachs or even unrelated foreachs (like the cols and rows foreachs in my example).

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Wrap the table with: `<div data-bind='template: { afterRender: myPostProcessingLogic }'>.` Then do whatever you need to do in myPostProsssingLogic. This will only be called when the table is first rendered however. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8k8V5/2237/):

```
 <div data-bind='template: { afterRender: myPostProcessingLogic }'> 
<table data-role="table" id="report-table" class="ui-body-a ui-shadow ui-responsive table-stripe"
    data-column-btn-theme="a" data-column-btn-text="Spalten..." data-column-popup-theme="a" data-mode="columntoggle"">
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
            <th data-bind="text: $data.Caption, attr: { 'data-priority': 1 + Math.floor($index() / 4) }"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: rows, afterRender: tableRowAfterRender }">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns">
            <!-- ko template: { name: $data.template } -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, "myPostProcessingLogic" runs once like you mentioned, but I need the "refresh" to run every time a new table has been rendered. When it renders initially, it is empty, with no cols and rows, and jQuery Mobile cannot enhance it. So at least each time columns have been added dynamically, the "myPostProcessingLogic" would need to run, therefore this approach does not work in my situation.

Comment: When you say "every time a new table has been rendered" do you replace the entire table or simply add/remove rows?

Comment: Usually (it is a one page app) the table gets a different set of columns and rows.

Comment: In that case then, there's a simple modification to my template that I think will work for you: Add a data: binding to the template, the template will be regenerated whenever the binding changes and then myPostProcessingLogic will be run again. Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8k8V5/2241/). Note that you would need to wrap the inner html with <div data-bind='with:$parent'>. To test it out, play with the "Advanced Options" in the result pane. In your code, instead of replacing all the rows and columns in your arrays, you would need to new up new arrays and assign to the observable

Comment: I added the data binding but it does not seem to work in my scenario. The "refresh" is always called before the table is rendered. I noticed, that if you add new rows in your fiddle, the alert will also show up before the row is being rendered. But the other operations in your fiddle seem to render first and the show the alert - as wanted. It seems hard to predict when ko renders what.

Comment: I think if you gave me a fiddle, I could figure out a solution for you otherwise, I'm just guessing :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use binding **init**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.init = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        var action = valueAccessor();
        if (typeof action === 'function') {
            setTimeout(action.bind(viewModel, element), 0);
        }
    }
};
```

Like this:

```
ko.components.register('simple-component', {
    viewModel: function(params) {        
        this.title = params.title;
        this.initHandler = function() {
            console.log('DOM of component has been built.');
        };
    },
    template:
        '<div data-bind="init: initHandler">\
            Title is: <span data-bind="text: title"></span>\
        </div>'
});
```

Information for more complex cases is here - http://blog.atott.ru/2015/08/dom-built-event-for-knockout-components.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way of doing it. Here is the process

Assign a class to your row

```
<tr class="row" data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns">
```

Check in your function with if condition

```
if(data.Items().length == $('row').length){
    $("#report-table").table("refresh")
}
```

Or call any event manually

```
$('#report-table').trigger('click')
```

Hope that's helpful to you.

EDITS:

Create a new observable and set it to false.

```
self.EnableTimeOut = ko.observable(false)
```

Now set it true according to your requirement. This is only example

```
if(data.Items().length == $('row').length && data.Items().length > 0){
    self.EnableTimeOut(true)
    $("#report-table").table("refresh")
}
```

And finally

Wrap it in condition

```
setTimeout(function () { 
    if(self.EnableTimeOut()){
        $("#report-table").table("refresh"); 
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks, this simplifies the object comparison (I am not sure if it will be faster, since it required more DOM comparison in return). However, the "setTimeout" is still required, if I do the table("refresh") without setTimeout, it is too early, the table is not ready to be refreshed and the jQuery enhancement does not work in full.

Comment: for this you can play with a flag. set a new observable to false. When it is run first time, make it true. Then, when calling set time out use condition to run only when it is set to true.

Comment: Did you add the "EnableTimeOut" to make sure, that the refresh is being run only once? My problem is not that I cannot make the refresh run only once, my problem rather is, that I do not know a way to refresh when the rows and columns have been rendered. I have to call ´$("#report-table").table("refresh")´ after knockout rendered the columns and rows.