# Firing actions after foreach finishes in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-3.2

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552042/knockoutjs-execute-callback-after-foreach-finishes-rendering) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254317/success-callback-after-knockout-js-finishes-rendering-all-the-elements?rq=1) one about the topic, but none of them seem to solve my problem.

I'm trying to initialize a javascript plugin (BootStrap javascript tooltip) for an element within each row of a table.

To do it, the table has to be rendered in the DOM. And that's where the problem is.
As far as I know, knockout.js doesn't provide a proper way to know when a `foreach` has render the whole table.

I've tried to solve it by applying the solution provided in the first link I posted, which is by creating a custom binding, but this doesn't work in my case. 
I guess because the data is being displayed by calling an API from an AJAX call.

[Reproduction of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/xveEP/259/)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.doSomething = {
    update: function (element) {
        console.log("table loaded???");

        //applying the tooltip
        $('.actions').tooltip({
            title: 'Actions'
        });
    }
};

function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.myItems= ko.observableArray(['A', 'B', 'C']);

    //emulating the delay of calling an external API 
    self.getdata = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.myItems.push('D');
            self.myItems.push('E');
            self.myItems.push('F');
        }, 200);       
    };

    self.addItem = function () {
        this.myItems.push('New item');
    };

    //getting the data on loading    
    self.getdata();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I would prefer not to use the `afterRender` callback provided by Knockout.js for `foreach` cases because that way the plugin would have to be initialized on every iteration rather than just once at the end.

The only solution I found for it was to apply a `setTimeout`, before applying the tooltip plugin, but it is far from ideal:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.doSomething = {
    update: function (element) {
        console.log("table loaded???");

        setTimeout(function(){
            //applying the tooltip
            $('.actions').tooltip({
                title: 'Actions'
            });
        }, 2000);
    }
};
```

The other solution was to call the `tooltip` plugin after getting the data from the API:

```
//emulating the delay of calling an external API 
self.getdata = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        //simulating 
        $.get(url, function(data){
            self.orders(data);
            self.loading(false);

            $('.actions').tooltip({
                title: 'Actions'
            });
        });
    }, 200);       
};
```

Is there any better approach to it?

Comment: Have you seen [Knockstrap](http://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/)?  It has bindings to help bridge the gap between knockout & bootstrap.  The very first example is for tooltips - may help you out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option that mixes some of what you already know in a different way that might be more palatable.

http://jsfiddle.net/xveEP/260/

I first added a variable to the viewmodel called `tooltipHandle`. This variable will be a reference (or pointer) to any `setTimeout` calls that are made for applying the tooltips.

I created a custom binding for the `<li>` elements rather than for the parent `<ul>` element. This custom binding first clears out any existing `setTimeout` instances for adding the tooltip. Then it creates a new `setTimeout` instance that will run in 5ms. The function in this `setTimeout` will apply the tooltip to all elements with the `.actions` class that have not already had the tooltip applied to them.

In your example, there are 6 total elements added: 3 immediately and 3 200ms later. My binding will execute 6 times, however, it will only apply the tooltips twice: once for the first 3 and once for the second 3. Since I am clearing out the `tooltipHandle` before it can execute the `setTimeout` function, it only runs after the 3rd item for each of the 2 sets has finished binding. I added a `console.log` call in the `setTimeout` function so that you will see that it is only called 2 times in your previous example.

In addition the binding will execute when you click the Add button and will only apply the tooltip to the newly added element.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: myItems">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, doSomething2: true" class="actions"></li>
</ul>
```

---

```
ko.bindingHandlers.doSomething2 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        clearTimeout(bindingContext.$parent.tooltipHandle);
        bindingContext.$parent.tooltipHandle = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.actions:not([data-original-title])').tooltip({
                title: 'Actions'
            });
            window.console.log('tooltip applied');
        }, 5);
    }
};

function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.tooltipHandle = undefined;
    self.myItems= ko.observableArray(['A', 'B', 'C']);

    //emulating the delay of calling an external API 
    self.getdata = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.myItems.push('D');
            self.myItems.push('E');
            self.myItems.push('F');
        }, 200);       
    };

    self.addItem = function () {
        this.myItems.push('New item');
    };

    //getting the data on loading    
    self.getdata();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the delay! :) 
Btw, is there any reason why you use `bindingContext.$parent.tooltipHandle` instead of a normal `var tooltipHandle` ?

Comment: A local `var tooltipHandle` within the binding handler would mean that you could potentially have multiple calls to `.tooltip` that are unnecessary. Imagine if you bound 500 items at once. This would mean 500 `.tooltip` calls when only actually 1 call is needed. By centralizing the `tooltipHandle` in the parent ViewModel, the code will clear out any pending `.tooltip` calls. A local variable would not have the same effect.

Comment: What I meant was an external global `var tooltipHandle` and an internal `tooltipHandle = setTimeout(function() {`

Comment: I always try to limit scope and avoid global variables whenever possible.