# Is it possible to have knockout call a function when a view is rendered?

Tags: javascript, razor, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have this relatively simple .cshtml view with knockout:

```
<div class="selected-cluster" data-bind="visible: Selected()">
<div data-bind="foreach: {data: Topics(), as: 'topic'}" class="row">
    <!-- ko if: topic.Grid && topic.FirstIterative -->
    @Html.Partial("Partial/_TopicGrid")
    <!-- /ko --><!--END if: topic.Grid && topic.FirstIterative -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: topic.Grid -->
    @Html.Partial("Partial/_Topic")
    <!-- /ko --><!--END ifnot: topic.Grid -->
</div>
```

The viewmodel of course contains Topics(), and it contains a function that I want to have executed after the last element of Topics has been processed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps this other question answers yours:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254317/success-callback-after-knockout-js-finishes-rendering-all-the-elements

Comment: @JoseLuis afterRender does the trick indeed. Thank you!